# Usage of keyword `related_name` in `tortoise.field.ForeignKeyField`

Tags: python, postgresql, tortoise-orm

I have read the documentation of Tortoise-ORM, but, at least to me, the documentation isn't clear about the keyword `related_name` in `tortoise.field.ForeignKeyField`. It states only:

```
related_name:
    The attribute name on the related model to reverse resolve the foreign key.
```

I'm using Aerich (the Tortoise-ORM migration manager), and I cannot see a single reference to the `related_name`'s used in my model. I also checked the database `Postgres` and could not find any reference about it. Maybe I don't know where to look.

Unfortunately there is no simple practical examples in Tortoise-ORM documentation about this.

I have a very simple model, something like:

```
import tortoise

class Toy(tortoise.models.Model):
    id = tortoise.fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = tortoise.fields.CharField(max_length=32)
    owner = tortoise.fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Person", related_name='toys_owner')
    builder = tortoise.fields.ForeignKeyField("models.Person", related_name='toys_builder')

class Person(tortoise.models.Model):
    id = tortoise.fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = tortoise.fields.CharField(max_length=32)


async def main():
    await tortoise.Tortoise.init(
            db_url='sqlite://:memory:',
            modules={'models': ["__main__"]}
    )
    await tortoise.Tortoise.generate_schemas()

    person_a = await Person.create(name="Gepheto")
    person_b = await Person.create(name="Fairy")
    person_c = await Person.create(name="Nobody")
    pinocchio = await Toy.create(name="Pinocchio", builder=person_a, owner=person_b)
    print(pinocchio)
    await tortoise.Tortoise.close_connections()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tortoise.run_async(main())
```

How `related_name` works in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the tortoise is inspired by Django, you can check [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to get similar answers. It is used when you want to reach Person's Toys.

```
person_a.toys_builder.all()
```

This is why it is called a "reverse resolve" event.

Comment: =) thanks Deniz. Yes. I found that. It's too bad to use someone else documentation. =)

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries...

The `related_name` value can be used as a name to be referenced in the Foreign Model to access it in reverse direction.

Let's first show up the forward direction. In the example given, from a  Toy model instance (in this case `pinocchio`), find his `builder` or `owner` with:

```py
print(f"This is pinnochio owner {pinnochio.owner.name}")
print(f"This is pinnochio builder {pinnochio.owner.builder}")
```

The `related_name` allow us to do the same in opposite direction, from a `owner` or `builder`, find his/hers  toys and iterate over it. For example:

```py
person_b_owned_toys = await person_b.toys_owner.all()

for toy in person_b_owned_toys:
    print(toy.name)
```

Besides the method `all()`, the method `filter()` can also be used. Returning a `QuerySet` with only the entries that match the filter. For example:

```py
person_b_owned_toys = await person_b.toys_owner.filter(name='Pinocchio')

for toy in person_b_owned_toys:
    print(toy.name)
```

The valid `keys` on `filter` parameter in the reverse direction, are those from `Toys`, not from, `Person`.